# Override css inline styles using Outlook

Tags: html, css

I m using html/css templates to send emails and I want to override inline styles provided by users for all images

This code is working fine in IE/chrome but not in outlook:

```
<head>
  <!-- [if qte mso 9]>
    ‹style type="text/css">
         #emailContent img[style] {width: 300 !important; height:auto !important;}
    </style>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

any help on this ?